# sql distinct on one column of a group

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT inta, name, PHN#, FROM nydta.adres
WHERE inta <> ' '
```

I want the `distinct` for `inta` because alot of the time phone is blank so those are coming thru i do want all columns, but distinct for inta.

and secondly, `inta` is an internet address column.
i would like to *exclude* one domain like say

```
@excludethisdomain.com
```

Data looks like this

```
ACCOUNT@ALLSTARS.COM    GATES   LOU  212-555-1212   ALLSTARREADING
PHERWESTBARN@MSN.COM    BARN    HEAT 212-555-1212
PHERWESTBARN@MSN.COM    BARN    RALP                EARLS
```

So in the second and third, it's distinct bec of the email address.

Comment: giving sample data and desired output will help us to completely understand you

Comment: so you want to show `PHERWESTBARN@MSN.COM` with `HEAT` or `RALP` !!!?

Comment: just one of them, the main interest is the emails yes as u say and also how to filter a particular url?

Comment: @PinchasK it is very important question, if it doesnt matter which one to select - do not select it at all, it will make things simplier

Comment: if it doesn't matter why you want to select names!!!? or it's necessary and you want to select at least one name for every email?

Comment: what is your RDBMS? say to write the query for you

Comment: yes u would want a name per email if there is yes sir

Comment: its db2 but sql server should be fine

Comment: Sorry I didn't know you have commented and noticed a little late, I'm writing the answer, please feel free to give a feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to the comments under question, if you want to `select distinct emails` with `only one name` which does not *matter* which of the names are selected for the specific email then you can use subqueries to select the values:

```
select distinct 
    t.inta , 
    (select top 1 a.name from nydta.adres a where a.inta=t.inta) name,
    (select top 1 a.PHH from nydta.adres a where a.inta=t.inta) PHH
from 
    nydta.adres t
where 
    inta <> ' '
```